# Django Rest Framework return one model inside another model's detail view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Trying to build a forum clone. There are a list of boards. Each board contains a list of threads. Each thread contains a list of posts. I'm confused about some things.

1. Is the `BoardDetail` view returning a list of threads the correct approach?
2. I'm not sure how that can be achieved.

Here is my attempt.

`views.py`

```
class BoardDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    # what needs to be done here to return the threads belonging to a particular board?
    queryset = Thread.objects.filter()  
    serializer_class = ThreadSerializer
```

`models.py`

```
class Board(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board_admin = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='board_admin')
    board_moderator = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='board_moderator')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']


class Thread(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thread_admin = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='thread')
    board_id = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="thread")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

Comment: you probably want a nested serializer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using nested serializers, this is a simple example of how to do these nested serializers.

In Board model, parent model, add this function to fetch all threads related to a certain object by foreign key or id.

```
@property
def threads(self):
    return self.thread_set.all() # thread is the name of the child class
```

Then in your serializer class for Board, the parent class add a field to contain threads with the parent id, it must have the same name as of the property we just created in the Board model, parent model, and assigned the serializer of the Threads model serializer, child model

```
threads = ThreadsSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

Then, u must add threads in the fields for the Board serializer, parent model

```
fields = ('name','created','board_admin','board_moderator','threads')
```

this should allow you display all the threads related to a board.

Comment: Thanks. This worked even without the @property. Is it ok to not use that or will that cause problems down the line?